# addeventlistener not working when using directly under promise but working fine with settimeout under promise

Tags: javascript

in this code, everything is working fine but when I run code without using `settimeout` (inside promise) it does not work as it works initially. please explain reason for this ??
I think, issue is occurred due to `addeventListener` but don't know why?

using `settimoeout` in below code and works fine.

```
<script>
          function funName(p1,p2, p3) {
           //some work ......
        
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(() => {
               //some syn work
        
                div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handle() {
                  div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handle);
                  resolve(div);
                });
              }, 0);
            })
          }
          </script>
```

but after commenting out `settimeout` ,problem occur

```
<script>
          function funName(p1,p2, p3) {
           //some work ......
        
            return new Promise(resolve => {
              //setTimeout(() => {
               //some syn work
        
                div.addEventListener('transitionend', function handle() {
                  div.removeEventListener('transitionend', handle);
                  resolve(div);
                });
             // }, 0);
            })
          }
          </script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but setTimeout causing it to spontaneously work sounds like you might have a race condition. In your example you are trying to attach an event listener to `div` can you describe how/when `div` enters the DOM? Is it dependent on some other asynchronous operation?

Comment: Please post what exactly "*`//some work ......`*" and "*`//some syn work`*" are.

Comment: I remember something about transitions only being triggered on new dom elements if the changes to the dom are applied with a timeout, but this should be unrelated to installing the event listener itself.

Comment: i will update this problm soon...